# SQL Server Report Builder Datetime Format

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to set the start time as previous 10 minutes instead of now.

currently set to

```
=Now
```

I tried `Now -10` and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Now.AddMinutes(-10)`

Lots more here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx